# Can't compose pretty-entities and ASCII chars next to each other in emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am trying to write a symbol in pretty entities like 'DpH', where the 'D' is the uppercase delta symbol, \Delta in org-mode.

However, composing "\DeltapH" of course is not interpreted correctly and expands. I do not want however "\Delta pH" with the space in between.  Juxtaposing two symbols works fine because of the escape character but I cannot find how to do this with 'normal' characters, i.e. \Delta\Psi works.

How do I get this in emacs for quick note taking or will I have to just learn LaTeX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-symbols.html):

> If you need such a symbol inside a word, terminate it like this: '`\Aacute{}stor`'.

So `\Delta{}pH` renders as `ΔpH`.

Comment: I need to try and read more carefully, but I wish they would bullet point separate ideas more clearly. Thank you this makes note taking a breeze.